# Unity Animation Rigging isn't working proplery

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, inverse-kinematics

I've been using the animation rigging package for quite a while but I've never struggled with this issue. When I use the two bone constraint, the arm will weirdly twist. I've tried many things like redoing the rig on the model, making it humanoid instead of generic. But none of them work. I tried using a free IK asset to see if it was an issue with my animation or rig, but it actually worked fine. So, why does this happen when using the animation rigging package?

Here's a [gif](https://gfycat.com/goodenlightenedirishwaterspaniel) that shows the issue and [another](https://gfycat.com/prestigiousembellishedegg) that shows me moving the pose IK around

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the weight of that bone is wrong. The right arm's movement is altered by the left arm's somehow. I would check to see if you have any rig constraints in the right arm that could be altering it's transform and disable them, because maybe that's it. Otherwise, you would have to go to your modelling application and check if the weights are painted correctly for the right arm bones

And check weights for left arm bones as well, the problem could be in there.